# Asynchronous execution/operation with CompletableFuture in Java 8+

Tags: java, loops, asynchronous, parallel-processing, completable-future

In Java, is calling get() method while looping on CompletableFuture instances as good as doing synchronous operations although CompletableFuture is used for async calls?

Comment: It is as *bad* as doing synchronous operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'get()' waits until the future is completed. If that's what you want, it's what you use. There's no general rule.

For example, you might be using a method that is inherently asynchronous, but in your particular use, you **need** to wait for it to complete.  If so, then there's nothing wrong with waiting for it to complete!

You mention a loop. You might find it applicable to start all the tasks in the loop, collecting a list of futures, and then (outside the loop) wait for them all to complete.  That way you're getting some parallelism.

But as a general rule: it depends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @iggy. I meant collecting futures and then calling get method in loop on each future while iterating futures.

Comment: If you loop body contains `someValue = doSomething().get()` then you're running them sequentially and synchronously.